# Wireshark doesn't show outgoing traffic

Tags: wireshark, traffic

For some reason, when I open wireshark, it only displays incoming packets (and broadcast), but there isn't a single outgoing traffic.
I searched in google and there was something about interfering software, but none of them are active on my computer.

Does anyone know why does it happen and how to fix it?

Comment: What operating system is running on your machine?

Comment: @GuyHarris Windows 7

Comment: What type of interface are you capturing on - Ethernet, Wi-Fi, or other?

Comment: @GuyHarris Wi-Fi. Actually I chose every interface and still - no outgoing packets

Comment: Was promiscuous mode enabled (checked) when you did the capture?

Answer (score 15):

If you have "DNE Lightweight Filter" checked in your network adapter properties, uncheck it.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a lot. What does this do? Does disabling it have any side effects?

Comment: DNE Lightweight filter is a component used by some Cisco VPN products. If you disable it, your Cisco VPN connection may not work until you re-enable it.

Comment: This works for me... but as @J.T.Taylor says, it stops my SonicWall Global VPN client from connecting.

Answer (score 1):

I tried disabling the extra drivers on my adapter but that didn't work. Turns out my problem was that I had previously installed an older version of Wireshark and I suspect that [it's uninstaller failed to fully clean up after itself.](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/589)

If you've previously installed nmap for Windows or an older version of Wireshark, check that you don't have any extra npcap/loopback adapters that might be interfering.

This worked for me:

1. Uninstall Wireshark and npcap
2. Open the Device Manager and expand the Network adapters list
3. Right-click any loopback adapters and click Uninstall

Now, hopefully everything works when you re-install Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, Wi-Fi device drivers often mishandle promiscuous mode; one form of mishandling is failure to show outgoing packets.

In addition, promiscuous mode won't show you third-party traffic, so it doesn't help.

Try capturing with promiscuous mode turned off.

Comment: I've tried it and still... But then I upgraded to windows 10, installed wireshark and now it's working